# flask + gunicorn + mtls, send client credentials to flask to make some additional comprobations

Tags: python, flask, https, gunicorn, mtls

I have a flask + gunicorn api with mutual tls working but I need to inspect the client cert in flask, the problem is that gunicorn is the one to review the cert and do the mtls work, when the request arrived to my flask endpoint it does not have the client request, I now a solution with Nginx but in this case I cant use it.

Any idea of how can I send the client cert to the flask endpoint :)